# What is the difference between Option Menu and Panel Menu in Android?

Tags: android, optionmenu

I just created a Panel Menu by mistake with the auto-completion of Eclipse and did not realise it before I read my code. As I wanted to have an option menu, I didn't see the slight difference in the display so does anyone know what the difference(s) is/are between these 2 menus? Is there any advantage or drawback for using one or the other?
The only difference I saw was (I didn't go into details though):

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
```

or

```
public boolean onCreatePanelMenu(int featureId, Menu menu)
```

thanks
(Shouldn't this be a bounty?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`onCreatePanelMenu` is called after you call `addSubMenu` from the `Menu` class. Seems like a rather arcane and badly documented feature. Here is a reference from the [Beginning Android 2](http://books.google.com/books?id=QdcYzuQx0DYC&pg=PA127&lpg=PA127&dq=addsubmenu+oncreatepanelmenu&source=bl&ots=xKbmmvYXCV&sig=K0imAj-wNhjUGfxAo9wjJaVhftM&hl=en&ei=EgFuTNKIE9iRjAeQoK2oDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CBQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=addsubmenu%20oncreatepanelmenu&f=false) book.

Answer (score -3):

Well Sephy

The main difference between options menu an context menu that context menu pops up relatively to a option menu. It only pops up when particular menu option is pressed and not remains in the memory after it is dismissed.

Comment: You got me confused... You are speaking of context menu but in a way that does not looks like their common use...

Comment: @success_anil Sephy is talking about Options and Panel Menus which are different from Context Menus. 3 different things.